# classic email template - email recipients

Tags: email, email-template, user

a classic email template is currently being sent out to one user every time a 'funds request' is made.

I would like to add another user to also receive this email, but I cant find where to add the other users email address.

I've had a look in the process builder but cant find anything relevant - is there anywhere else I should check?

Comment: you should check the email alert related to the email action in process builder, there you can find all the recipients of the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check Email Alert Settings,

for that, Go to Quick find >> Search Email alert. then you can find the `Email alert` list under `Workflow & Approvals` Section

If that 2nd user already having salesforce account. You can add that 2nd user in `Recipients` settings in `Email alert` which having that `Email Template`. Then that 2nd user also get that email.

If that 2nd user is not an user in your org. You can use `Additional Emails` option to mention that user email. (But please note, you can only mention 5 email address in that option as max).

Please let me know if it helps.

Thanks.